# Any probability density can be written as a sum of Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, estimation, gaussian

In Gaussian sum mixture model, any probability density function (pdf) can be written as a sum of Gaussian. Lets consider here any $n$-dimensional vector $x$ follows Gaussian distribution with mean $\hat{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and covariance $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ can be written as 
\begin{equation}
p(x) = \mathcal{N}(x;\, \hat{x},\, P) = \sum_{i=1}^{N_f} w_{i} \mathcal{N}(x;\, \hat{x}_i, \, P_i),   
\end{equation}
where $w_i$ represents the weight of the $i$-th Gaussian pdf, and $\sum_{i=1}^{N_f} w_{i}=1$. $\hat{x}_i$ and $P_i$ are the $i$-th mean and covariance respectively. Here my specific question is how to generate $w_i$, $\hat{x}_i$ and $P_i$ for any $N_f$.

Any kind of suggestion will be of great help.

Comment: Is $\hat{x}_i$ a vector, and $P_i$ a matrix? If the right-hand side denotes a mixture of multivariate Gaussians, then it typically is not Gaussian, as the left-hand side seems to denote.

Comment: Yes $\hat{x}_i$ is a vector, and $P_i$ is any matrix. So can we not split any Gaussian pdf into mixture of Gaussian?

Comment: Actually in filtering theory (Nonlinear estimation), we consider the pdfs as Gaussian but actually it may also be not. And by taking that assumption (Gaussian), we proceed for nonlinear filtering like cubature Kalman filter, Unscented Kalman filter etc. And there we can also use Gaussian sum filter to further improve the performance.

Comment: Why do you need to split a Gaussian pdf further into Gaussians? You can just choose "$N_f=1$" or alternatively "$w_1=1$ and $w_2=\cdots=w_{N_f}=0$" in that case.

Comment: As angryavian points out, a weighted sum of Gaussian PDFs is not necessarily Gaussian (even in 1 dimension). Also, it is not true that any PDF can be represented by a finite sum of Gaussians. I think you really have a situation with $n$ random variales $X_1, ..., X_n$ and you independently pick one with probabilities $w_1, ..., w_n$ so that $$ Y = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} X_1 & \mbox{with prob $w_1$} \\ ...  & ... \\ X_n & \mbox{with prob $w_n$} \end{array}\right.$$ In which case $E[Y]= \sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{E[Y|\mbox{Case $i$}]}_{E[X_i]}w_i$ by the law of total expectation.